# How to characterize the additive group of a simple module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If $R$ is a unital ring and $M$ is a simple R-module, then I want to show that $M$ viewed as an additive abelian group is either a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, or a direct sum of copies of the cyclic group $Z_p$ for prime $p$. I think I've made substantial progress on the case where $M$ has an element of finite order:

Let $a \in M$ be a nonzero element of finite order. Because $M$ is simple then it must be generated by every nonzero element, hence if $z \in M$ then I can find $r \in R$ such that $z = ra$. Thus if $a + ... + a = 0$, then by multiplying by $r$ I have that $z + ... + z = 0$, which shows that $|z| \leq |a|$. But this exact same argument also shows $|a| \leq |z|$, hence they are equal. Thus all non-zero elements have the same order. Now this is where I got stuck. How would I show that this implies that $M$ is a direct sum of copies of $Z_p$? It is intuitively seems to be the case, but I can't think of an argument. Also, I have no idea how to approach the case where all nonzero elements of $M$ have infinite order.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a simple left $R$-module. Consider the endomorphism ring $\newcommand{\Endo}{\operatorname{Endo}}\Endo_R(M)$. Since $M$ is simple, every endomorphism $T:M\to M$ is either invertible or 0 (since either its image is 0 and kernel is all of $M$, or its image is all of $M$ and its kernel is 0). Thus $\Endo_R(M)$ is a division algebra. Now consider its characteristic subring, $A$. Since $\Endo_R(M)$, is a division algebra, every nonzero element of $A$ is invertible in $\Endo_R(M)$, so $\Endo_R(M)$ contains $\newcommand{\Frac}{\operatorname{Frac}}k:=\Frac A$, the field of fractions of $A$. Thus $k$ acts on $M$. This makes $M$ a $k$-vector space, and as $k$-vector spaces (and thus as abelian groups), $M\cong k^{\oplus I}$ for some index set $I$. However $k$ is either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$, depending on the characteristic of $\Endo_R(M)$. Thus we have the desired result.